# Slapd gives an error when creating a user

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ldap, slapd

Im creating a user in a LDAP server in ubuntu 20.04, but it gives me this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeUXD.png)

The config of the user is this:
[user code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CRrC.png)

Im using slapd and ldap-utils services

i tried to leave only that user in the file, but didnt worked, i didnt tried much moe as im pretty now to ldap and ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

ok sorry, im dumb XD
i wrote objetClass instead of objectClass, now its okey .-.